# Mysql INNER JOIN after a LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, query-optimization

I have below query;

```
SELECT * FROM product pr
LEFT OUTER JOIN product_field_value pfv ON pfv.product_id = pr.id AND pfv.product_field_id = 64
INNER JOIN product_colour pc ON pc.id = pfv.value
```

Now, not every product has product_field_value corresponding to the :

```
ON pfv.product_id = pr.id AND pfv.product_field_id = 64
```

But those that have corresponding rows in the `product_field_value` table, should inner join into `product_colour` also.

But as you imagine, `INNER JOIN` to `product_colour` table after a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to `product_field_value` table, filters out those that DOESN'T HAVE `product_field_value` relation.

So I've come up with this solution;

```
SELECT * FROM product pr
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT colourPfv.name as name,pfv.product_id as productId,pfv.product_field_id as productFieldId FROM product_field_value pfv
              INNER JOIN product_colour colourPfv on pfv.value = colourPfv.id) colourRel ON colourRel.productId = pr.id AND colourRel.productFieldId = 64
```

And this query returns both those that DOESN'T HAVE corresponding product_field_value and those that HAVE.

But performance for latest query is too slow.

Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you move the logic to the `WHERE` clause, is performance better?

```
SELECT * FROM product pr
LEFT JOIN product_field_value pfv 
    ON pfv.product_id = pr.id AND pfv.product_field_id = 64
LEFT JOIN product_colour pc ON pc.id = pfv.value
WHERE pfv.product_id IS NULL OR (pfv.product_id IS NOT NULL AND pc.id IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Thank you.. This actually worked with very nice performance. But is WHERE clause irrelevant in this situation ? Because I've removed it and it worked nicely again..

Comment: @paroxit: as far as I understand your question, this implements the logic that you want (ie this is equivalent to your last query, that `left join`s an `inner join` subquery).

Comment: I'm sorry, I beleive your version is more correct than mine. Because in your version, you also check whether there is a product_colour corresponds to the pfv.value relation (since there could be none). Thank you again

Comment: I think `WHERE pfv.product_id IS NULL OR (pfv.product_id IS NOT NULL AND pc.id IS NOT NULL)` can be simplified to `WHERE pfv.product_id IS NULL OR pc.id IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM product pr LEFT JOIN
     product_field_value pfv
     ON pfv.product_id = pr.id AND
        pfv.product_field_id = 64 LEFT JOIN
     product_colour pc
     ON pc.id = pfv.value;
```

If there is no match on the second table, then the last `ON` clause evaluates to `NULL` which is treated as false.